# Python Flask app on EC2 AWS

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, flask

I'm trying to run a simple python flask app on  Amazon Linux AMI. I'm able to show  the Amazon Linux AMI test page but when I try create the proper configuration to run my app I'm facing always the same problem.

```
[Fri Sep 16 12:56:39.190230 2016] [:error] [pid 17977] [remote 77.246.17.229:59978] mod_wsgi (pid=17977): Target WSGI script '/var/www/flaskapp/app.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Fri Sep 16 12:56:39.190239 2016] [:error] [pid 17977] [remote 77.246.17.229:59978] mod_wsgi (pid=17977): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/flaskapp/app.wsgi'.
[Fri Sep 16 12:56:39.190252 2016] [:error] [pid 17977] [remote 77.246.17.229:59978] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Sep 16 12:56:39.190271 2016] [:error] [pid 17977] [remote 77.246.17.229:59978]   File "/var/www/flaskapp/app.wsgi", line 26, in <module>
[Fri Sep 16 12:56:39.190288 2016] [:error] [pid 17977] [remote 77.246.17.229:59978]     from app import app as application
[Fri Sep 16 12:56:39.190294 2016] [:error] [pid 17977] [remote 77.246.17.229:59978]   File "/var/www/flaskapp/app.py", line 1, in <module>
[Fri Sep 16 12:56:39.190303 2016] [:error] [pid 17977] [remote 77.246.17.229:59978]     from flask import Flask
[Fri Sep 16 12:56:39.190316 2016] [:error] [pid 17977] [remote 77.246.17.229:59978] ImportError: No module named flask
```

My app.py:

```
from flask import Flask
app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

My app.wsgi:

```
import sys
import site
import os
# Add virtualenv site packages
site.addsitedir(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages'))

activate_this = '/var/www/flaskapp/env/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))

# Path of execution
sys.path.insert(0,'/var/www/flaskapp')

#import the app
from app import app as application
```

and my httpd.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName ec2....
    WSGIDaemonProcess app threads=5 home=/var/www/flaskapp/ python-path=/var/www/flaskapp/env/lib/python2.7 threads=1

    DocumentRoot /var/www/flaskapp

    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/flaskapp/app.wsgi
    <Directory /var/www/flaskapp>
            WSGIProcessGroup app
            WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

If I look at what is installed in the virtualenv wit pip freeze I get this:

```
click==6.6
Flask==0.11.1
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.8
MarkupSafe==0.23
Werkzeug==0.11.11
```

so Flask is installed. Why I'm not able to import it? What I'm doing wrong?

thanks

Comment: The `python-path` input to `WSGIDaemonProcess` should point at a `site-packages` directory.

Comment: If I change python-path to /var/www/flaskapp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages I'll get that:
from markupsafe import Markup, escape, soft_unicode 
ImportError: No module named markupsafe

Answer (score -1):

On EC2/EB, deploy the flask application through the console by uploading a zip file. 
Keep the flask app like a normal flask app on your PC. I guess AWS takes care of WSGI automatically.

Just do the following :

```
application = app = Flask(__name__)
......
......
application.run()
```

save this main file as "application.py"

Zip and upload through AWS console and it will run.

Answer (score -1):

go to the /var/www/html folder and install flask in that directory.
Use sudo command for the same.
Then your app should work,

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide the reason for this solution to work.

Comment: which web server are you  using? Ngynix or Apache?